# Как получить список статей в зависимости от выбранной категории в виджете?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress

Всем привет! Делаю сайт, используя CMS Wordpress. Создаю виджет, получаю все категории в переменную и вывожу их в select, значениями value являются id категорий. Как мне в зависимости от выбранной категории получить id и вытащить все статьи данной категории, которые пойдут в следующий select?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Когда пользователь  выбирает значение первого `select`, в браузере возникает событие, которое можно перехватить в функции `change` в jQuery. В этой функции надо извлечь выбор первого `select`, и отправить `ajax` запрос.

Полученные из `ajax` данные вставить во второй `select` с помощью jQuery.